# how to show 'user authentication token' check box in deployment group register script

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I can not see the check box option that say "Use a personal access token in the script for authentication" in my deployment group details page, knowing that i created a deployment group token... how can i solve this problem [this image is my deployment group page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANAzZ.png)

[this image with checkbox option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3tU1.png)

Comment: can you share the image when you didn't show it?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk  sure, i edited my question...

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps or TFS (2019)? do you the admin?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk   TFS (2019), yes i am the admin...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the check box option that say "Use a personal access token in the script for authentication" in my deployment group

I'm afraid that the image you reference is configuring deployment group in **VSTS(VS Team Services)** not tfs. There's no checkbox like this in tfs, no matter what the version is.

As normal, we don't need PAT to configure it in tfs because the server of tfs is locally. Just copy the script and paste it in powershell. Run it as administrator will successfully added the agent.

If you indeed want to use a PAT with TFS, your server must be configured with HTTPS, see [web site setting and security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/websitesettings?view=tfs-2017).

Comment: @ Merlin Liang - MSFT thank you very much for your respond... i change my url to https and it ask me for the pat now ...